Collection of morphisms $\alpha : F \Rightarrow G$ abiding by $\alpha_A = G(f^{-1}) \alpha_B F(f)$ — Is this notion studied?
Let $F, G : C \to D$ be parallel functors and let $\alpha$ be a collection of morphisms $\alpha = \{ \alpha_c : Fc \to Gc \}_{c \in \mathrm{Ob}(C)}$.
We call $\alpha$ natural if for any morphism $f \in \mathrm{Mor}_C(a,b)$ the following diagram commutes

I'm interested in a similar condition asking that for any $f, g \in \mathrm{Mor}_C(a,b)$ with $g f = 1$ we have that

Conceptually this attempts to capture the notion that $\alpha$ "does not observe" $a$. Naturality does this a little bit already, but this second condition asks for it more pointedly.
Has this condition been given attention already? Does it have a name?
We might be able to view this commutativity condition as presence of a morphism in the appropriate subcategory of the twisted-arrow category $\mathrm{Tw}(D)$, but I'm not sure if that gets us anywhere.

Regarding your "weird braces... couldn't get the Text to do what you wanted"; I used \{,\} to get ${,}$. Is this what you wanted? Usually, if a piece of punctuation is a Tex command the way you get the actual punctuation is by placing a backslash before it

@FShrike Thanks! For some reason using \{ was disappearing in the post preview (but now it's not)

By the way I would think of your condition as "naturally preserving direct summands". It's essentially saying you have maps $Fb\to Gb$ which, when restricted to the summand (along a split monomorphism $a\hookrightarrow b$) the image remains in the summand (lands in $Ga$). I don't have a reference for this ever being useful or anything though, it's a corollary of naturality but definitely doesn't imply naturality
